# Using Lookup IIF in conditional Formatting

Tags: reporting-services, lookup, highlight, fill, iif

I need to highlight the dates that are in another dataset, this date is 90 days from a renewal date, ive used IIF(LOOKUP, but getting nowhere, this is what i have used

```
=iif(
LOOKUP(Fields!PERSON_ID.Value,Fields!DESTINATION_BASE.Value, 
Fields!THREE_MONTH_DATE.Value,
 "safe") = dateadd(dateinterval.Day,-90,Today()),"YELLOW","WHITE")
```

Comment: Oracle sql 2017

Comment: VISUAL STUDIO 2012

Comment: Assuming your logic is correct, this will return "Yellow" when the row in dataset "safe" that has a DESTINTATION_BASE field that matches PERSON_ID has a THREE_MONTH_DATE fields that is exactly 90 days ago. It should work if all date fields are actually dates (not strings) and if you only want the highlight to show for a single day. A row that was highlighted today would not be tomorrow. Not sure if that's helpful or not. If not, edit your question and explain what is not working